# Rails AJAX a Destroy Action

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use AJAX on a friendships list where the "Request Friendship" button turns into a "Cancel Request" button and then back again if clicked a second time. The first click works, the ajax on the "Cancel Request" button does not.

On line 2 of the destroy.js.erb I get a:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

I know it's not working because the user_id is not passed in the URL for the destroy as it is for the create, but I don't know how to fix it.

**Friendships Controller**

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_user, only: [:create]
    before_action :set_friendship, only: [:destroy, :accept]

    def create
        @friendship = current_user.request_friendship(@user)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friendship Requested"}
            format.js
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @friendship.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friendship Removed"}
            format.js
        end
    end

    def accept
        @friendship.accept_friendship
        @friendship.create_activity key: 'friendship.accepted', owner: @friendship.user, recipient: @friendship.friend
        @friendship.create_activity key: 'friendship.accepted', owner: @friendship.friend, recipient: @friendship.user
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friendship Accepted"}
            format.js
        end
    end

    private

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def set_friendship
        @friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**Create JS**

```
$('.js-not-friend-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.action-button-for-<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= j action_buttons(@user) %>');
});
```

**Destroy JS**

```
$('.js-cancel-request-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.action-button-for-<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= j action_buttons(@user) %>');
});
```

**Users Helper**

```
def action_buttons(user)
    case current_user.friendship_status(user) when "friends"
        link_to "Cancel Friendship", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true,  class: "js-cancel-friendship-btn btn btn-danger btn-xs mr10"
    when "pending"
        link_to "Cancel Request", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "js-cancel-request-btn btn btn-danger btn-xs mr10"
    when "requested"
        link_to("Accept Friendship", accept_friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :put, :remote => true, class: "js-accept-friendship-btn btn btn-success btn-xs mr10") +
        link_to("Decline", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "js-decline-friendship-btn btn btn-default btn-xs  mr10")
    when "not_friends"
        link_to "Add as Friend", friendships_path(user_id: user.id), method: :post, :remote => true, class: "js-not-friend-btn btn btn-success btn-xs mr10"
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following line to my destroy action in order to use @user in the destroy.js.erb:

```
@user = @friendship.user == current_user ? @friendship.friend : @friendship.user
```